# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.max function using int

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get this error on this line

```
var idnumber = db.h_ptmast.Max(r => r.ptmast_regno);
```

the datatype of ptmast_regno is int

if i wirte the above as

```
int idnumber = db.h_ptmast.Max(r => r.ptmast_regno);
```

then the whole line gives error as cannot convert type string to int

Comment: `ptmast_regno` is of type `string`. You should convert it to `int` before using in `Max`.

Comment: in db its int only.......how else do i convert it?

Comment: var idnumber = db.h_ptmast.Max(r => (Convert.ToInt32(r.ptmast_regno)));

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression...........now its giving this error